# i want to know how to show/hide a block of code with a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to create a custom angularjs directive that will show or hide a block of code enclosed by the directive element after some calculations are done on the attributes of the directive. I get no errors but both blocks of code show up at the same time even though they have different conditions.

**here is the DOM sample**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myist">
<category-count my-collection="myList" category="{{item.ref}}" tagType="info">
    <!--some code here -->
</category-count>

<category-count class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 no-padding text-center"  my-collection="myList" category="{{item.ref}}" tagType="msg">
    <!--block of code here-->
</category-count>
```

**here is the directive as it is now**

```
    myApp.directive('categoryCount', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        bindToController:true,
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        multiElement: true,
        scope: {
            myCollection: '=myCollection',
            category: '@category',
            tagType: '@tagType'
        },
        controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
        controller: function($scope) {

            var self = this;
            self.myCollection= $scope.myCollection;
            self.category = $scope.category;
            self.tagType  = $scope.tagType;
            self.result = 0;

             self.count =  function(){

                for(var x = 0; x < self.myCollection.length;x++){

                    var item = self.myCollection[x];
                    console.log("category @ x = "+x+" is :"+self.category);
                    if(item.question.category.ref == self.category){
                        self.result++;
                        return;
                    }
                }


            };

        },

        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {

            return{
                pre: function(scope, element, attributes, myCtrl){

                    myCtrl.count();
                },
                post: function(scope, element, attributes, myCtrl){


                    console.log("result in directive is: "+myCtrl.result+" for tag : "+ myCtrl.tagType);

                    if(myCtrl.result != null && typeof myCtrl.result != "undefined" && typeof myCtrl.tagType != "undefined"){
                        if(myCtrl.result <= 0){


                            attributes.$set('ngShow' , myCtrl.tagType == "msg" );


                        }
                        else if(myCtrl.result > 0){


                            attributes.$set('ngShow' , myCtrl.tagType != "msg");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with angularjs directives: ng-show and ng-hide instead of a custom directive.

Comment: The logic that determines whether or not to show the element is a little too complex for ngShow and ngHide. It requires computation on a collection of items based on some criterion.

Comment: You can try ng-show="doMyComputations(X,Y,Z...) " and make this function on controller side. Also if the computation is the same for ng-hide, you can preserve this value in a scope variable.